# Add random integer value to elements in list, but sum of list must not change

Tags: python, random, data-science

I try to randomize some data in python, with following formula:

```
limit = 10 # value bewteen 0 and 100, const. for all values on the dataset
for old in objects:
    new_v = old + old * int(math.ceil(random_limit(limit))
    new_objects.append(new_v)

def random_limit(limit):
    # create value between [-1; 1)
    rand = np.random.rand()*2.0 - 1.0; 
    return ((rand * float(limit)) / 100.0)
```

The idea is, to set a procentual limit for the randomizing on the initial `old_value`. This limit has to be the same for all data.

Now it would be nice if could achieve `sum(objects) == sum(new_objects)`. I don't have any idea how to start and if this is even possible under the `limit` condition. Any ideas?

Example:

```
objects:          new_values: 
    [1000,             [1100,
     1200,              1100,
     0900,              0845,
     5700,              5300, 
     8000]              8455]
  sum = 16800           sum = 16800
```

So the sum of the old 5 values and the sum of the 5 new values should be the same, but the values change with the limit and random condition. In this example limit should be 10%, so no value changes more than 10%. For 1000 10% gets added, so it is 1100. For 1200 -9.09% gets added, so the new value is 1100. This goes on for the other values with a limit between [-10%, 10%).

Comment: could you add an example with numbers?

Comment: For every number you will change you could select a second number in the list and modify it by the opposite amount. Depending on your constraints for randomisation you might need to add some more constraints but that would seem like a reasonably simple approach?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the 10% rule, because if you have 50000 the amount changed can be 5000 which is bigger than the other numbers. So I would say one way to do is order the numbers from smaller to bigger and calculate the change to the 1st number, then apply the opposite to the 2nd number, then calculate to 3rd one and so on. You cannot have fully independent random numbers because the sum must match! Notice you are only generating half the numbers and the second half is dependent on the 1st half

That above can work for an even amount of numbers only. To an odd amount, you could split the calculated difference into the next 2 numbers, for example.

So your example data ordered would be

```
    [1000,             [ 900,
     1200,              1000,
      900,              1200,
     5700,              5700, 
     8000]              8000]
```

Then you can generate random numbers:

```
RAND1 = random from -90 to +90
RAND2 = -RAND1
RAND3 = random from -120 to 120
RAND4 = -RAND3 / 2
RAND5 = -RAND3 / 2
```

Then you add up your list of random numbers with the original list. If the original order is important, you need to keep track of it before running the calculation.

```
lets say RAND1 = -30 and RAND3 = 100

[ 870,
 1030,
 1300,
 5650, 
 8050]
```